# Kill a server listening on specific port

Tags: php, websocket, server, kill

i am executing this php file to stop my server from listening mode
command:  echo exec('npx kill-port 9005');
it display this message on screen: Process on port 9005 killed
but when i open xampp port 9005 is still on listening mode what's the error can anyone elaborate me or give me a solution to stop server (php socket) to stop listening but

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you can find the PID of the process listening to a specific port by:

```
netstat -aon | find "9005"
```

Get the PID and use this command to kill this process by:

```
taskkill /F /pid PID
```

If netstat didn't return anything, then simply port 9005 is not being listened to.